# Change every string in a cell array and covert it to numbers without loop?

Tags: matlab, for-loop, vectorization

I have following cell array of strings:

```
daycell = 

'd100'
'd104'
'd105'
```

I would like to make an array of numbers from it like this:

```
array =

100   104   105
```

**I can accomplish it using loop:**

```
daycell = {'d100';'d104';'d105'}
array = [];
for g = 1:1:length(daycell)
    array(g) = str2double(daycell{g}(2:end));
end
```

**Is is possible to do it without loop?** Is is even better using it without loop? The `daycell` has much more rows in real.

---

So far I am able to eliminate the `d` letter using:

```
daym = cell2mat(daycell);
daynoD = daym(:,2:end);

daynoD =

100
104
105
```

but I do not know what to do with the matrix of characters.

Comment: You can use `str2num(daynoD)`.

Comment: @H.Muster ahh..true, I tried str2double but it is not that clever function, thx

Comment: There is a difference between `str2num` and `str2double`!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is to use `cellfun`

```
cellfun(@(x)str2double(x(2:end)),daycell);
```

Comment: Nice one, Matlab has so many useful functions that it is difficult to keep track on them. .